# "Update to Recommended Settings" warnings in Xcode v9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have faced a problem related to "Update to Recommended Settings".(Please have a look on the picture below) There are many warnings but I cannot figure out what mistakes I have made which leads so many errors.

I am using `xcode v9.2`, along with `react v16.2.0`, `react-native v0.52.0`, and some other dependencies.

Appreciate for any help or suggestion. If you need any files to figure the problem out, please feel free to ask me. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This happens due to the Xcode version update and API updates. Just click on Warning icons and update all changes. I think It's not create any issue with compilation. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks @RenishDadhaniya. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @Renish Dadhaniya, what if I don't want to change the minimum target version of iOS, because that's what Xcode wants me to do. I think that "just click on it and ..." is advice that should come with a disclaimer telling the developer to actually read what is going to get updated!