# React Native Build Error After Updating to Recommended Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have created a new React Native project. When I build it in Xcode I get 180+ warnings but it builds just fine. Most of the warnings are `Update to recommended settings`. I have gone through and updated them as [another question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374930/update-to-recommended-settings-warnings-in-xcode-v9-2) suggested. However, when I update to the recommended settings on the `RCTText` library I now get a build error. Updating did not result in any code changes so I cannot revert. The error says the following:

```
RCTText
Semantic Issue
Implementing unavailable method
RCTUITextView.m
Method 'setText:' declared here
```

This is the line of text it doesn't like.

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
```

Since this is code in a library, I'm not sure how to handle it and I can't find any information on how to revert changes that were made during an "update to recommended settings."

Here are the versions I am running.

```
react-native: 0.56.0
xcode: 9.4.1
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue, and how?

Comment: @AlanSchambers unfortunately I was never able to resolve it. I ended up switching to Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixable by turning "Overriding Deprecated Objective-C Methods" to 'No' in the project's settings. [image: Change to No]